# using background image for headers

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, background-image

I have got an image which i have to used for my headers , I cant use fixed image as the header width changes depending on the header text, therefore i did 3 slices of an image , starting which wont repeat , middle slice which will repeat with the text and end slice image which should close the header, i have included the image , and the css which i am using , the end slice doesnt works , can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong :

```
<div class="product-item">
<div class="product-title">

<span><h3>@Model.Name</h3></span>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product-grid .product-item .product-title
{
background-image: url('images/first-slice.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0% 0%;
height:37px;
 }
.product-grid .product-item .product-title span
{
background-image: url('images/last-slice.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 100% 50%;
 height:37px;
 }

.product-grid .product-item .product-title h3
{
background-position: 50%;
background-image: url('images/middle-slice.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
 height:37px;
 margin-left:5px;
 }
```

Live test Website:[Website](http://www.teamlemon.co.uk/c/14/cholera-toxins)

First Image: [image: First-slice]
middle Image : [image]
End Slice : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
<span><h3>@Model.Name</h3></span>
```

to:

```
<div><h3>@Model.Name</h3></div>
```

The problem is that `span` is an inline element, on which setting a `height` will not work.

`<span><h3>@Model.Name</h3></span>` is also invalid HTML.

---

As pointed out by @ptriek, you also need to swap the order of backgrounds between elements.

This is the CSS that you need (assuming that you changed the `span` to a `div`):

```
.product-grid .product-item .product-title
{
    background-image: url('images/middle-slice.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.product-grid .product-item .product-title div
{
    background-image: url('images/first-slice.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
.product-grid .product-item .product-title h3
{
    background-image: url('images/last-slice.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 37px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: i just want to add an end image ,u mean should add another class instead of span something like :<div class"something"><h1>...</h1></div> and then add the styles on it

Comment: though it's semantically incorrect to have a h3 in a span, this is not the cause of the problem - the height of h3 makes the span take over the 37px height

Comment: so the correct way is to wrap up everything in divs and then add the styling

Comment: but the image width does not change depending on the text, i want to limit the the background image with text.

Comment: @MrA: It looks like this with the fixes in my answer applied: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XLbuf.png. If that's not what you want, I give up.

Comment: thanx , it has fixed d 80% of my requirement but the header should not expand till end it should wrap up as the header text ends

Comment: well in that case you should mention that in your question in the first place.

Comment: sorry for that , i tried using display:inline-block , it works now , but do inline-block is compatitble with all the versions

Answer (score 3):

The main problem was that the `h3` element has the same width as the containing `span`. This `span` has also be set to `display:block`, in order for `background-position` to function.

However, as said in the comments, in order for the HTML also to be valid, this span must be changed to a div.

Then, I just added a `margin-right:5px` to the `h3` element as well.

Finally, in order to have the text vertically centered, use `line-height` instead of `height`.

```
.product-grid.product-item.product-title
{
    background-image: url('images/last-slice.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100%;
    line-height:37px;
}

.product-grid.product-item.product-title h3
{
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url('images/middle-slice.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    line-height:height:37px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.product-grid.product-item.product-title div {
    background-image: url('images/first-slice.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0%;
    line-height:37px;
}
```

Comment: The HTML *should* be changed, because [it's invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Felavid&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2).

Answer (score 2):

The h3 (containing the repeated middle image) sits on top of the span, containing your right image.

Set the right image on the h3, and the repeated image on the span - that should fix it.

And better change the span to a div, since a span can't contain block elements like h3 (semantically incorrect)

Comment: but using div the new block-level element will be created , i was avoiding that , by including span just to change the style and the last image ..

Comment: what would be worse about adding a block-level element instead of an inline element? html rules state that an inline element (like span) cannot contain block-level elements (like h3). your code works, but it's just not correct...

Comment: i tried using another div within div , but image width does not change depending on the text.

Comment: even added display block to the h3 tag

Comment: just follow exaclty the instructions of @thirtydot - that will work

Answer (score 1):

Add more divs, it would be easier:

```
<div id=wrapper>
 <div id="bg_header">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="content">
  &nbsp;
  </div>
 <div id="bg_footer">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I've done this in many projects and this works in every major browser.